# How to createElement with looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Help, i want to do looping when the data is displayed to the div tag as the following code :

```
function GetDataFromServer() {

var url = "http://bertho.web.id/curl/services21/DataReadNP.php";
JSONP.get(url, {}, function(response){
    var listItem, container, dataList = document.getElementById("dataList"), str = "", str2 = "";
            for ( var i = 0; i < response.length; ++i ) {
                str += response[i].title;
                str2 += response[i].fetch_date;
            }

    listItem = document.createElement('div');
    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-type', 'item');
    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-img', 'images/icons/icon11.png');
    listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-title', str);
    listItem.innerHTML = str2;

    container = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(listItem);

    bb.imageList.apply([container]);

    dataList.appendChild(container.firstChild);

    if (bb.scroller) {
        bb.scroller.refresh();
    }

});  

}
```

To display the list to the screen :

```
function dataOnTheFly() {
   document.getElementById('waiting').style.display = 'none';
   GetDataFromServer()  
}
```

The data I want is displayed on the screen, but do not fit what I wanted.
Please see pictures below :

**http://s13.postimage.org/68w2zfmh3/data_BB.png**

I want to list this data looping until all the data on the server is taken.
How do I to get the results I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling up the URL given in your question, your data looks like this:

```
"items": [
 {
  "id": "30",
  "judul": "KATY PERRY: PART OF ME",
  "img": "http:\/\/bertho.web.id\/curl\/21proses\/images\/r_134760931680781_100x147.jpg",
  "desk": "Sebuah dokumentasi tentang kehidupan Katy Perry diatas maupun diluar panggung. [More]",
  "web": "http:\/\/www.21cineplex.com\/",
  "fetch_date": "15-09-2012 20:10:23"
 },
```

This is a `JSON` response, not a `JSONP` -- they are similar, but different. I'm not sure what your `JSONP` function does, so I can't tell you exactly how to proceed.

At some point, you need to run `JSON.parse()` on the data you receive.  Your library may nor may not do this for you.  If `typeof response === "string"` then it hasn't.

Once you have the `JSON` decoded to an object, then it is just a simple matter of looping

```
var items = response.items;
var l = items.length;
var i = 0;
var item;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  item = items[i];
  // Now you can do something with item
   listItem = document.createElement('div');
   listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-type', 'item');
   listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-img', item.img);
   listItem.setAttribute('data-bb-title', item.judul);
   // Don't forget to append listItem somewhere.
}
```

Comment: My recent server address for JSONP output : http://berthojoris.com/developer/services21/DataReadNP.php?callback=tmp123

And I use the example on this page : http://www.nonobtrusive.com/2010/05/20/lightweight-jsonp-without-any-3rd-party-libraries/

Comment: Update your question with exactly what you tried, and a better definition of "it didn't work." (my that phrase by ever struck from the English language.)  What didn't work? What error message did you get?